# Markdown editing help link to Google Prettify should be updated

Tags: feature-request

The "Google Prettify" link here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting currently points to ye olde and deprecated http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

It should probably point to https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I recall a comment from an SE Dev that they post-pone this until the link goes dark early 2016 but I can't find it anymore so maybe I only dreamed it...

Comment: It's better to fix it now rather than waiting until 2016 IMHO...